# Spark SQL table lock during ALTER TABLE tbl PARTITION SET LOCATION

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

We're using Spark SQL 2.2.0 with Hive Metastore (on HDInsight).
We have external tables build on partitioned parquet files stored on Azure BLOB. The data will be sent to the BLOB in parquet format, we have no influence on this.

We need to accept partitionwise data updates (aka. restatements) with minimal impact on:

- the downstream systems that run queries on the data (avoid breaking queries and long waiting, etc.)
- the data update process (avoid long waiting and complex logic whenever possible)

We are considering doing something like this as a way to perform the updates (nothing very special):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl PARTITION(YEAR=2018, MONTH=1, DAY=30) 
SET LOCATION 'wasb:///mylocation/table/20180130/v2'
```

What table (or partition) locking mechanisms/logic can we expect? I've googled and the answer is unclear to me.

Are there any parameters in Hive/Spark can we use to control it, except for turning all the concurrency on/off with `hive.support.concurrency`?

Any other ways to solve this kind of problem? We've tested direct overwriting parquet files in particular partition folders but it seems more cumbersome as it requires running `recoverPartitions` and recreating DataFrames over and over.

Comment: Dominik, were you able to find a solution for this issue or not yet ?